# Need assistance with a snippet for WP Job Manager

Tags: php, wordpress

I am wondering if you're able to help me with the following WordPress customization. We're using the WP Job Manager plugin (https://wpjobmanager.com/) and I'd need a little help with a slug/permalink edit.

In the documentation is an article available which explains the following: at the current situation links are generated as follows: domain.com/job/job-name. However, I need the following structure: domain.com/job-category/job-name.

Please check: https://wpjobmanager.com/document/tutorial-changing-the-job-slugpermalink/

The article explains this. Please check the code on: Example: Adding the category to the base URL. When I remove the 'job' in the following code, the job listings are working fine, but the rest of my website returns in a 404 error (also after saving the permalinks).

```
$args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'job/%category%';
```

To

```
$args['rewrite']['slug'] = '%category%';
```

Full code:

```
    function job_listing_post_type_link( $permalink, $post ) {
   // Abort if post is not a job
   if ( $post->post_type !== 'job_listing' )
       return $permalink;

   // Abort early if the placeholder rewrite tag isn't in the generated URL
   if ( false === strpos( $permalink, '%' ) )
       return $permalink;

   // Get the custom taxonomy terms in use by this post
   $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'job_listing_category', array( 'orderby' => 'parent', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );

   if ( empty( $terms ) ) {
       // If no terms are assigned to this post, use a string instead (can't leave the placeholder there)
       $job_listing_category = _x( 'uncat', 'slug' );
   } else {
       // Replace the placeholder rewrite tag with the first term's slug
       $first_term = array_shift( $terms );
       $job_listing_category = $first_term->slug;
   }

   $find = array(
       '%category%'
   );

   $replace = array(
       $job_listing_category
   );

   $replace = array_map( 'sanitize_title', $replace );

   $permalink = str_replace( $find, $replace, $permalink );

   return $permalink;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'job_listing_post_type_link', 10, 2 );

function change_job_listing_slug( $args ) {
  $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'job/%category%';
  return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_job_listing', 'change_job_listing_slug' );
```

Comment: Volunteers here on Stack Overflow don't charge for their help, so I have edited your offer of payment out. As long as there is sufficient detail in the question, and it is not too broad a question, you should get help here.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that!

Answer (score -1):

Well, I was also stuck in some type of error once. But in my case, I was creating everything my self. So I change the template accordingly.

However, In you case, I think it relates to URL Re-Writing. Please check out the following links. I hope those will help.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-change-custom-post-type-permalinks-in-wordpress/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule
https://paulund.co.uk/rewrite-urls-wordpress

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am not able to edit the 'job' slug. Please check this screenshot: http://imgur.com/4uU7cj3